# error: aggregate ‘food_type a’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The compiler does not allow me to run this code:

> error: aggregate ‘food_type a’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Unless I add parenthesis `()` after instantiating `a`, `f1`, `f2`, `f3` which prevents `cout` functions to show anything. Why does it happen?

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Animal { Cat, Dog, Duck};

class Food
{
public:
    Food()
    {
        std::cout<<"Food called"<<std::endl;
    }
};

template <enum Animal,class food_type>
class Ecosystem;

template<>
class Ecosystem<Animal::Cat,class food_type>
{
public:
    Ecosystem()
    {
        std::cout<<"Cat constructor called"<<std::endl;
        food_type a;
    }
};

template <>
class Ecosystem<Animal::Dog,class food_type>
{
public:
    Ecosystem()
    {
        std::cout<<"Dog constructor called"<<std::endl;
        food_type a;
    }
};


template <>
class Ecosystem<Animal::Duck,class food_type>
{
public:
    Ecosystem()
    {
        std::cout<<"Duck constructor called"<<std::endl;
        food_type a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Ecosystem<Animal::Cat,Food> f1;
    Ecosystem<Animal::Dog,Food> f2;
    Ecosystem<Animal::Duck,Food> f3;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to partially specialize the template, it should be done like this:

```
template<class food_type>
class Ecosystem<Animal::Cat,food_type>
```

instead of:

```
template<>
class Ecosystem<Animal::Cat,class food_type>
```

In the second case what you're actually doing is fully specializing based on the incomplete type `class food_type`, which is what's causing the error.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed my code. Just want to know why we should not add `()` when defining an object. how does it prevent constructor from being called without any compiler error?

Comment: @barej `food_type a();` is not an object instantiation. It's a function declaration.

Comment: I thought defining function inside another function is forbidden.

Comment: @barej: *declaration* is different than *definition*.